# HP Proliant ML30 Gen10: VMware ESXi 7.0 does not recognize hard drives (Flash virtual)

Tags: vmware, esxi

I have a problem when I try to install VMware ESXi 7.0 U2 on my HP Proliant ML30 Gen10.
I have 1 HD 4TB SATA and 1 SSD 1TB SATA on RAID 0
I test also with 2 HD 4TB SATA on RAID 1 and I have the same problem.
I install VMware ESXi without problem through a pendrive (less 16GB, more 16GB), but, when I enter to the ESXi interface, I have a “Flash virtual 0B used 0B capacity” and my ESXi does not recognize my hard drives and I can’t do anything.
What could I do to solve this problem?
Thank so much.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Lk2.jpg)

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for this site. Please look at [stackoverflow.com/tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). I think you may have better luck in [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Which esxi image are you using? Try to download HPE custom image for esxi, it's has all drivers for your hardware. Can you tell me which hba model has the server ? If you have an smart array serie S its not compatible, you should install esxi without raid configured.